# Rules to redeclare abstract method public?

Tags: java, abstract

Since the "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/jls10.pdf 8.4.3.1 abstract Methods" is silent about redeclaring protected abstract methods in subclasses as public, id like to ask if it does not only compile but where it is mentioned in the docs.

Assume in abstract class i have `abstract protected void fromAbove(String d);`
 and extending the class i redeclare with `public void fromAbove(String data) {....}`
 is this valid?

Comment: What happens when you test this?

Comment: it does compile like i mentioned, but where to read up on it, what is it called i am doing.